# can not resolve djanngo model issue

Tags: django, model

I created three apps in my project, and when go to questions models it cannot find a model in Quiz models. please help. Im right in the directory where my manage.py is

I tried to change path of my project interpreter, nothing changed

Comment: Please add your code for models and well as project directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this steps

1. After creation apps add app to settings.
2. on the terminal run commands:

python manage.py migrate,
python managa.py makemigrations

Comment: sure. after i made Quiz model in quizes.models i ran makemigations and migrate. and when go to another app - questions and in questions.models triend to from quizes.models import Quiz it still had a mistake

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).